# How to get a list of child ids for a named category?

Tags: plugin-development

I believe I could do this with either get_categories() or wp_list_categories() and passing a 'child_of' parameter, for example, but that would return a much larger dataset than I need.

Is there a direct call that returns the child ids for any category as a simple list (1,2,3,5, etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
get_terms( 'category', "child_of=$parent&fields=ids" );
// should return an array containing the ID's of children of term $parent
```

Comment: @goldenapples: Is this correct? var_dump(get_terms('category', "child_of=1&fields=ids" ))? (returns array(0) { })

Comment: It looks right to me, are there children to fetch? And are they non-empty? Look at the available arguments here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L721

Comment: just add 'show_empty=true' to the second param I think.

Comment: Actually, I think the problem is that I'm seeding $parent with the category id, not the term_id. But shouldn't they be the same? I'm trying to list all children of the uncategorized category, which is id tag_ID 1.

Comment: How about get_term_children(1,'category') ?

Comment: Yes the category ID should be the same as its term ID. You're getting a non-error response, so you have the syntax right. Try removing the child_of argument and see what you get...

Comment: `get_term_children` should work, but it'll still return all the objects, which is what I thought you didn't want. `get_terms` has the "fields" parameter, so you could return only the ids.

Comment: @GA, I found the problem. I had previously set a list_terms_exclusions filter which excluded children of uncategorized from the resultset.